# Wait for data to be passed before execution

Tags: swift, asynchronous, closures, wait

I have a function right here in my tableViewCell and I am printing the count of the data. But when I'm looking at the log:

```
Table View Cell TRAINING COUNT is 0
Table View TRAINING COUNT is 3
Table View Cell TRAINING COUNT is 0
Table View TRAINING COUNT is 4
Table View Cell TRAINING COUNT is 0
Table View TRAINING COUNT is 1
```

the print on tableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var trainings = [Training]()
    var trainingCategories = [TrainingCategory]()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        print("Table View Cell TRAINING COUNT is \(trainings.count)")
    }
}
```

is performed first before the print in each row in the tableViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TrainingTableCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
    var trainingsUnderCategory = [Training]()
    for counter in 0 ..< trainings.count{
        if trainingCategories[indexPath.section].id! == trainings[counter].category_id!{
            trainingsUnderCategory.append(trainings[counter])
        }
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = .white
    cell.trainings = trainingsUnderCategory
    print("Table View TRAINING COUNT is \(cell.trainings .count)")
    return cell
}
```

I can't see how I can use closures here, or am I wrong? Thanks for anyone who'll answer!

Comment: because your cell init `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TrainingTableCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell` starts before your set `cell.trainings = trainingsUnderCategory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` is called when you create the cell by  `dequeueReusableCell` function call. Everything works as it should. If you'd like to configure the `HomeTableViewCell` with given `trainings` data you can do it by creating a function. Here is an example:

```
// cellForRowAt
...
cell.setTrainings(trainings)
return cell

// HomeTableViewCell
...
func setTrainings(_ trainings: [Training]) {
    self.trainings = trainings
    // Do configuration here

}
```

You don't necessarily need to create a function within the cell you can also do the configuration in `cellForRowAt` function but separating the configuration would be better code wise.

Comment: ,big thank you, my man! Although some modifications, you meant self.trainings and cell.setTrainings(trainingsUnderCategories). But it worked like a charm! Now my problem is setting the delegate for the collection view cell in the collection view in the table view cell in the table view, haha.

Comment: You are welcome and glad to hear that it worked. I changed `this` to `self` sorry for that :)